# Add multiple users in ADD terraform/ create module to use in other env

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

Im currently looking for help with AAD and terraform. I need to create multiple users and make this as a modeule so I can use it in few environments. Does anyone did that and would be able to help?

variable.tf

```
variable "users" {
    type = map
    default = [
        [
        "user1",
        "user1display",
        "password119823"
        ],

        [
        "user2",
        "user2display",
        "password119823"
        ]
    ]
}
```

This variable return an error, that this wrong type. How should I declare it?

main.tf

```
resource "azuread_user" "team_user" {
  for_each = toset(var.users)  
  user_principal_name = "${each.value[0]}@${var.domain}"
  display_name = each.value[1]
  password = each.value[2]
  }
```

Is this loop done in good way? I'm kinda noob with creating multiple resources.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "Is this loop done in good way?" - run it, and please let us know how did it go.

Comment: I have changes variable type for list and code is valid now. Loop returned error:Error: Invalid for_each set argument
│ 
│   on aad.tf line 5, in resource "azuread_user" "team_user":
│    5:   for_each = toset(var.users)  
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.users is list of tuple with 2 elements
│ 
│ The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: "for_each" supports maps and sets of strings, but you have provided a set containing type tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for_each` can't iterate over list of list. So you can change it to a map of lists as follows:

```
resource "azuread_user" "team_user" {
  for_each = {for idx, user in var.users: idx=>user}  
  user_principal_name = "${each.value[0]}@${var.domain}"
  display_name = each.value[1]
  password = each.value[2]
}
```

Comment: Have one more question. How can I convers my variable to a .tfvars file? When I add tfvars file with following: users = [[ "user1", "user1display","password119823"], ["user2","user2display","password119823"]    ]
terraform is asking me to "Enter value for var.users"

Comment: @SanHolo I would suggest making new question for the new issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71691322/how-to-convert-variable-tf-into-tfvars-terraform If you could take a look Marcin that would be great.

Comment: hi @Marcin 
can you please look at this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75186892/terraform-trying-to-replace-existing-resource-when-new-user-is-added

Answer (score 0):

I think your data structure passing to for_each is not ideal. It would look much neater if you simply go for something like this.

---> sorry the edited working solution :)

```
variable "users" {
    type = map(any)
    default =  {
  user1 = {
    display = "user1display"
    password = "password119823"
  }
  user2 = {
    display = "user2display"
    password = "password119823"
  }
}

resource "azuread_user" "team_user" {
  for_each = var.users
  
  user_principal_name = "${each.key}@${var.domain}"
  display_name = each.value.display
  password = each.value.password
}
```

Comment: │ Error: Invalid type specification
│ 
│   on variables.tf line 20, in variable "users":
│   20:         user1 = {
│   21:             display = "user1display"
│   22:             password = "password119823"
│   23:         }
│ 
│ A type specification is either a primitive type keyword (bool, number, string) or a complex type constructor call, like list(string).

Comment: sorry..edited..