# how to convert variable.tf into tfvars. Terraform

Tags: terraform

How can I convert this variable into tfvars variable?

```
variable "users" {
    type = list
    default = [
        [
        "user1",
        "user1display",
        "password119823"
        ],

        [
        "user2",
        "user2display",
        "password119823"
        ]
    ]
}
```

When I do following:

terraform.tfvars

```
users = [

 [
 "user1",
 "user1display",
 "password119823"
 ], 
 [
 "user2",
 "user2display",
 "password119823"]
]
```

Terraform is asking me for add value for users.

Thank you.

Comment: This looks fine. Are you sure your put your files in correct folders?

Comment: How did it go? Did you check your folders or perhaps file names?

Comment: Hey, filename was wrong, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As this is written [here](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables#variable-definitions-tfvars-files)

> A variable definitions file uses the same basic syntax as Terraform language files, but consists only of variable name assignments:

with such example:

```
image_id = "ami-abc123"
availability_zone_names = [
  "us-east-1a",
  "us-west-1c",
]
```

Could you remove emtpy line a try again:

```
users = [
 [
 "user1",
 "user1display",
 "password119823"
 ], 
 [
 "user2",
 "user2display",
 "password119823"]
]
```